# If I own Google Pixel and iPhone with same Google account, do I get unlimited upload for Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

Google Photos changed the policy so that only Google Pixel owners get to upload to Google Photos for free.

If I own an iPhone and Google Pixel both connected to the same Google account, does iPhone also get unlimited uploads?

Answer (score 2):

**The offer is device-dependent and only applicable for Pixel devices.**

This is explained in more detail on [Google Photos Help - Choose the upload size of your photos & videos](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid#zippy=%2Cpixel-a-%2Cpixel) under Android's tab - "Pixel storage info".

> **Important:** If you have a Pixel 5 device or earlier, your current backup options and benefits remain unchanged. Photos and videos backed up in Storage saver quality (previously named High quality) from your Pixel 2-5 devices will continue to receive unlimited free storage. However, as of June 1, 2021 **any new photos or videos you back up *from other devices* in Storage saver quality will count toward your Google Account storage**.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Note that such info is not mentioned on the "Computer" tab and "iPhone & iPad" tab. Even for Android devices that are usually more prone to hack, [the available hacks to disguise them as Pixel devices have also been patched.](https://www.xda-developers.com/enable-google-photos-unlimited-storage/)

The in-app Settings also makes it clear based on the device:

[image] [image]

<sup>Left: Pixel 3a, "*Free and unlimited on this device*" | Right: Nexus 5, "*Store more at a slightly reduced quality*"</sup>